# C# programmatic install of a filter driver?

Tags: c#, winapi, driver, installation

I'm currently using setup.dll to install a filter driver in  a programmatic way.
the following is my code:

```
    protected bool INFSetup(string path_to_inf, bool Install)
    {
        string exe = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "rundll32.exe");
        if (File.Exists(exe) && File.Exists(path_to_inf))
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                string FileName = exe;
                string Arguments = @"SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection " + (Install ? "DefaultInstall" : "DefaultUninstall") + " 128 " + path_to_inf;
                Debug.Writeline("Executing: '" + FileName + "' with arguments: " + Arguments);
                ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName, Arguments);
                StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo = StartInfo;
                if (proc.Start())
                {
                    if (proc.WaitForExit(10000))
                    {
                        return (proc.ExitCode == 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Writeline("INFSetup: proc.WaitForExit() returned false");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Writeline("INFSetup: proc.Start() returned false");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Writeline("Caught Execption while installing INF: " + e.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

although the code works fine, I was wondering if there is a way to do the same with native Win32 calls?
it would be great if anyone has a sample c# code?
Thanks
Henry

Answer (score 0):

As the `rundll` command line suggests [`InstallHinfSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also exported from SETUPAPI.DLL and is thus p/invokable. An MSFT bod posted a p/invoke signature [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2103b5e0-19cb-4823-9542-952ca7953b8b/installing-driver-using-inf-file-in-c):

> ```
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
>
>
> [DllImport("Setupapi.dll", EntryPoint="InstallHinfSection", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
> public static extern void InstallHinfSection( 
>     [In] IntPtr hwnd, 
>     [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle, 
>     [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer, 
>     int nCmdShow); 
>
> InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "my path", 0);
> ```